# Adding a custom image to a chartjs bar chart

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, bar-chart, background-color, onload

I am trying to add an image instead of a color to the dataset of a bar graph in Chart.js using Vue.js. All examples I found to implement this seem to indicate that the graph needs to be already rendered before applying this fill (refer to https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html).

I am pulling the chart from a context before modifying it again. When I use this approach:

```
<Bar v-if="loaded" :data="chartData" :options="chartOptions" ref="bar"/>
this.$refs.bar.getContext('2d')
```

It fails with "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')." I am calling this chart render on a Vue mounted hook.

is there any way to add a background on the chartjs framework, as a part on the initial render, passing those in on the "chartData" object.

Able to get it  to work, still seeing issues though  it fails to load the background img intermittently.                                                                                                             Not able to recreate the issue  see https://jsfiddle.net/emsq26co/
It fails to load the background (for some reason comes up on hover) think it relates to not being able to delete the old chart , Chart.getchart does not work on 2.7.2 tried using cdnjs for 4.3.0 , chart does not come up.

Works fine in sandbox ;  https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-maxwell-dtqlq3?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue , no intermittent issue observed.            Have uploaded an example on this issue @ https://github.com/webtechux/vue.git , seems to work on edge. Chrome and opera not so much.
Any resize of the bowser allows the background to come through,  again including 'maintainAspectRatio' on the options, also seems to cause issues.

Comment: No, the chart doesn't have to be rendered before applying the image background. The image itself however has to be loaded and you have to have access at least to `document` to create a canvas element. The example section you referenced, more precisely [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html#patterns-and-gradients) in the first code example sets the image background in the configuration object, before rendering. You may replace there `document.getElementById('canvas')` with `document.createElement('canvas')` to use a new canvas instead of the existing one.

Comment: using vuejs 3 i am seeing Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext') , when i attempt to access the '2d' context from within mounted () on the options API.   also if i create a new chart object how does that bind to the existing canvas ?

Comment: It seems to me that you are still trying to use the chart canvas, which is not available until vue has rendered the chart. Try creating a new canvas, if you have access to `document`, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqkvL9zh/) for that method. If you create a stackblitz or codesandbox with your code,  we'll be able to give advice for the specifics of your problem.

Comment: see above for details

Comment: If you use `chart.destroy` it's very likely to get flickering and issues on resize.

Comment: there is no flickering , the only issue i see is that the background does not update intermittently, besides update of chart data itself (onload of the image and setting the background properties to createPattern only) does not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image onload allocates only an event handler , so there is need to wait on the process to complete. so define a promise , having the onload resolve and finally awaiting on the promise , is required to sort out any partial background render that may occur.
Have updated github with changes for anyone looking for details.
Would think the original chartjs snippet should also reflect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).